# Deleting multiple features (selected by expression) at once using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, select-by-attribute

I'm trying to select multiple features at once to do batch editing. The first selection is supposed to be the expression within the request, but I can't seem to get anything to select. I want the selection to be deleted.

```
##layer=vector
##zone_index=field layer
##subty_index=field layer
##sfha_index=field layer

from qgis.core import *import qgis.utils
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

layer=processing.getObject(layer)

layer.startEditing()

request = QgsExpression(u"\"zone_index\"='AREA NOT INCLUDED' OR \"zone_index\"='OPEN WATER' OR (\"sfha_index\" = 'F' AND \"zone_index\" = 'D')")

it= layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( request))

ids = [i.id() for i in it]
print ids

layer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)


layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You was on the right way, but you forgave using a provider for deleting the features (you don't need to set a selection before deleting the features). Furthermore, I edited just a bit your code when creating the `request`.

I think that this code should work (it worked for me using another `request` expression):

```py
##layer=vector
##fld_zone=field layer
##zone_subty=field layer
##sfha=field layer

from qgis.core import * 

layer=processing.getObject(layer)

prov = layer.dataProvider() # Define the provider

request = '"%s"=\'AREA NOT INCLUDED\' OR "%s"=\'OPEN WATER\' OR ("%s"=\'F\' AND "%s"=\'D\')' % (zone_index, zone_index, sfha_index, zone_index)
it= layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(request))

prov.deleteFeatures([i.id() for i in it]) # Delete the selected features
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work.

Comment: Does it show some error or simply nothing happens to your layer?

Comment: Nothing happens to the layer when I run it.

Comment: Ok, this means that there is some error in the string where you set the request. However, I edited the request in the code: it only depends from it, but I can't help you for this because I don't know how your data are structured (I hope you will understand how the syntax for a request should be to best fit it to your case). Let me know if it works by now!

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked also for you ;)

Comment: If you want this to run as fast as possible, change `it= layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(request))` to `it= layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(request)).setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry).setSubsetOfAttributes([])` See http://nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts/ for an explanation why this helps.